# Implementing IEnumerator/ IEnumerable with IDispose error

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I've been trying to build in IEnumorator to allow my to use a foreach Statement to quickly insert a large number of rows extracted from a JSON formatted string into these nested objects. The Applines class consists exclusively of String Get/Set statements.

For some reason I'm getting three errors pointing to the class header. I can't understand
a) why and how Do I need to implement IDisposable
b) Why dose the compiler disagree with my return types.

> 'AppAnnieImport' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()'. 'AppAnnieImport.GetEnumerator()' cannot implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.Collections.IEnumerator'.
>
> 'AppAnnieImport' does not implement interface member 'System.IDisposable.Dispose()'
>
> 'AppAnnieImport' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator.Current'. 'AppAnnieImport.Current' cannot implement 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator.Current' because it does not have the matching return type of 'AppLines'.

```
public class AppAnnieImport : IEnumerator<AppLines>, IEnumerable<AppLines>
{
    public int code { get; set; }
    public DateTime end_date { get; set; }
    public string vertical { get; set; }
    public string granularity { get; set; }
    public string device { get; set; }
    public List<AppLines> AppLine { get; set; }
    private int position;

    //IEnumerator and IEnumerable require these methods.
    public IEnumerator<AppLines> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (IEnumerator<AppLines>)this;
    }

    //IEnumerator
    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        position++;
        return (position < AppLine.Count);
    }

    //IEnumerable
    public void Reset()
    { position = 0; }

    //IEnumerable
    public object Current
    {
        get { return (AppLine.ToArray())[position] ; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Place the cursor on `IEnumerator<AppLines>` and press Ctrl+. and choose implement interfaces. Basically you need to implement both generic and non generic version of `GetEnumerator`.

Comment: Nothing to add to the compiler explanation of problem.

Comment: I would not make the class both IEnumerable and IEnumerator, implement IEnumerable, if you need a custom IEnumerator, make it a separate class.

Comment: I agree with @LasseV.Karlsen at least in a public class (it can sometimes be handy to implement both in a private or internal class, where the potential for confusion is much less).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`IEnumerator<T>` inherits from `IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you so have to implement it too and provide a `Dispose` method.

`IEnumerator<T>` inherits from `IEnumerator`, so you have to implement it too and provide a `GetEnumerator()` function returning an `IEnumerator`.

[`IEnumerator<T>` defines a property `Current` which returns a `T`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58e146b7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so you have to implement one.

---

I guess the confusion arises from the fact that the generic `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerator<T>` inherit from the non-generic versions (`IEnumerable`  and `IEnumerator`), demanding to implement methods with the same name but different return value types; and that `IEnumerator<T>` inherits from `IDisposable` while `IEnumerator` does not.

---

So, in the end, your class should look something like

```
public class AppAnnieImport : IEnumerator<AppLines>, IEnumerable<AppLines>
{
    public int code { get; set; }
    public DateTime end_date { get; set; }
    public string vertical { get; set; }
    public string granularity { get; set; }
    public string device { get; set; }
    public List<AppLines> AppLine { get; set; }
    private int position;

    //IEnumerator and IEnumerable require these methods.
    public IEnumerator<AppLines> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (IEnumerator<AppLines>)this;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (IEnumerator<AppLines>)this;
    }

    //IEnumerator
    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        position++;
        return (position < AppLine.Count);
    }

    //IEnumerable
    public void Reset()
    { position = 0; }

    //IEnumerable
    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get { return (AppLine.ToArray())[position] ; }
    }

    public AppLines Current
    {
        get { return (AppLine.ToArray())[position] ; }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // do something or not
    }
}
```

making use of explicit interface implementation (you may also want to get rid of the code duplication).

Comment: thaks, this is perfect

Answer (score 0):

start with reusing the inner list's methods and layer in your custom logic afterwards:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class AppLines { }
    public class AppAnnieImport : IEnumerator<AppLines>, IEnumerable<AppLines>
    {
        public int code { get; set; }
        public DateTime end_date { get; set; }
        public string vertical { get; set; }
        public string granularity { get; set; }
        public string device { get; set; }
        public List<AppLines> appLines { get; set; }
        private int position;

        AppLines IEnumerator<AppLines>.Current
        {
            get { return ((IEnumerator<AppLines>)this.appLines).Current; }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            ((IEnumerator<AppLines>)this.appLines).Dispose();
        }

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.appLines.GetEnumerator();
        }

        object System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get { return ((System.Collections.IEnumerator)this.appLines).Current; }
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            return ((System.Collections.IEnumerator)this.appLines).MoveNext();
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            ((System.Collections.IEnumerator)this.appLines).Reset();
        }

        IEnumerator<AppLines> IEnumerable<AppLines>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ((IEnumerable<AppLines>)this.appLines).GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```